# Why are we being twitter spammed?

Tags: spam, twitter, botattack

This is a search relating to us:

https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/scirra

We're getting a of of new accounts tweeting:

`The Layers Bar - Scirra.com`

Firstly this is not us doing it as we're quite proud of doing everything completely whitehat.  Also this tweet doesn't make any sense, "The Layers Bar" seems to be referring to a manual entry of ours.  They all seem to be new accounts with no followers and no prior tweets coming in like clockwork every hour.

- Does anyone know why this could be happening?
- Could this harm us?
- It it possible to find out the source of this?

I should mention I'm hesitant to report them all as spam because it could look like we are the culprits.

Comment: are they twitting your site ? or using your hashtag to spam their site ? In either case you should report these accounts.

Comment: @Mahesh they are tweeting our URL :(

Comment: Report them by submitting ticket. https://support.twitter.com/forms/abusiveuser

Comment: @Mahesh - You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mahesh didn't come back to write this up as an answer I figured I would.

It is going to be hard to work out why spammers do what they do - it could have been a bug in their system so they spammed the wrong URL out, or they could be trying to damage your name on Twitter, or a host of other things. My advice would be to not lose too much sleep over it.

The best course of action (as Mahesh has commented) is to report them by submitting a ticket to this URL - [support.twitter.com/forms/abusiveuser](http://support.twitter.com/forms/abusiveuser)